# Check file names and delete files with lower number in suffix

Tags: powershell

I have a following task on PowerShell: 
I need to check files on remote machines:
**For instance:**

```
Get-ChildItem \\ServerName\data\
```

In this folder I have following files:

```
standard_file.0.tst
standard_file.1.tst
standard_file.2.tst
standard_file.3.tst
```

So, i need to delete files with lower number prefix (based on file name).
In the end, into the folder should be only one file with biggest prefix.
**For instance:**
`standard_file.3.tst`

I broke up my mind - and have no any ideas how to perform this.
Could you please push me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any approach you have tried at all? This reads like a code writing request.

Comment: Does the folder only contain files with the same _prefix_ e.i. `standard_file`? or are there other files in that folder containing suffixes?

Comment: In general, previous answer shed some light already, but this is really valid point.  
I have other files in this folder and these other files should not be affected.
I've adapted code a bit, because `-SkipLast 1` doesn't work for some reason.
So, currently i have following:

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `regex` to get the number and cast it to an `int`. Then sort the filenames by the number using the [Sort-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113403) cmdlet so the file with the highest number will be the last. Then you select all objects using [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) and skip the last one and finally remove it using [Remove-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373):

```cs
Get-ChildItem '\ServerName\data\' | 
    Sort-Object { [int][regex]::Match($_, '.*?(\d+)\.[^.]+$').Groups[1].Value } |
    Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |
    Remove-Item
```

**Regex:**

```
.*?(\d+)\.[^.]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

This will gather all the files in the path that have numerical suffixes in their names. The way that is done is by using a regex to match all of the digits on the end of the `basename`. Sorting on the result of that match in descending order will put the wanted file on the top of the list. We then remove the remaining files by skipping that first result.

```
$path = "c:\temp"
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -match "\.\d+$"} |
    Sort-Object -Property {$_.BaseName -match "\.(\d+)$";[int]$Matches[1]} -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Remove `-WhatIf` when you are sure that it will remove the files you want.

Comment: Matt, thank you so much!  
This exactly that i trying to reach whole morning!  
I'll learn `Regex` because it's really powerful thing!  
Thanks once again - you are the man!  
All the best!  
=)